# How do I reference a cell range from one worksheet to another using excel formulas?

Tags: excel

I have a single worksheet with sheets Sheet1 and Sheet2 and I am trying to reference a range of cells from Sheet2 to Sheet1

I know how to reference worksheet cells such as `=Sheet2!A1`  but how can I do the same for a cell range such as `A1:F1` I tried `=Sheet2!A1:F1` but it does not like the syntax.

I need to use Excel Formulas for this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Got it, I downloaded a custom concatenation function and then just referenced its cells

**Code**

```
    Function concat(useThis As Range, Optional delim As String) As String
 ' this function will concatenate a range of cells and return one string
 ' useful when you have a rather large range of cells that you need to add up
 Dim retVal, dlm As String
 retVal = ""
 If delim = Null Then
 dlm = ""
 Else
 dlm = delim
 End If
 For Each cell In useThis
 if cstr(cell.value)<>"" and cstr(cell.value)<>" " then
 retVal = retVal & cstr(cell.Value) & dlm
 end if
 Next
 If dlm <> "" Then
 retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - Len(dlm))
 End If
 concat = retVal
 End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple ---

I have created a Sheet 2 with 4 cells and Sheet 1 with a single Cell with a Formula:

```
=SUM(Sheet2!B3:E3)
```

Note, trying as you stated, it does not make sense to assign a Single Cell a value from a range. Send it to a Formula that uses a range to do something with it.

Comment: I am actually not doing math, I am trying to dump text from a cell range.

Answer (score 4):

The formula that you have is fine.  But, after entering it, you need to hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  in order to apply it to the range of values.  Specifically:

1. Select the range of values in the destination sheet.
2. Enter into the formula panel your desired formula, e.g. `=Sheet2!A1:F1`
3. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the formula to the range.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to concatenate multiple cells from different sheets, and you also want to add a delimiter between the content of each cell, the most straightforward way to do it is:

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A4, ", ", Sheet2!A5)
```

This works only for a limited number of referenced cells, but it is fast if you have only of few of these cells that you want to map.

Answer (score 2):

You can put an equal formula, then copy it so reference the whole range (one cell goes into one cell)

```
=Sheet2!A1
```

If you need to concatenate the results, you'll need a longer formula, or a user-defined function (i.e. macro).

```
=Sheet2!A1&Sheet2!B1&Sheet2!C1&Sheet2!D1&Sheet2!E1&Sheet2!F1
```

Comment: The cell references I need are around 200 cells long and that's just for one line ;( would take a massive amount of work to do them all

Answer (score 2):

Its quite simple but not easy to discover --- [Go here to read more](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa). its from the official microsoft website

**Step 1** -
Click the cell or range of the source sheet (that contains the data you want to link to)

**Step 2**
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or go to the Home tab, and in the Clipboard group, click Copy  Button image .

**Step 3**
Clipboard group on the `Home` tab

**Step 4**
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, or go to the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click Paste Link  Button. By default, the Paste Options  Button image button appears when you paste copied data.

**Step 5**
Click the Paste Options button, and then click Paste Link .

Answer (score 1):

If these worksheets reside in the same workbook, a simple solution would be to name the range, and have the formula refer to the named range.  To name a range, select it, right click, and provide it with a meaningful name with Workbook scope.

For example `=Sheet1!$A$1:$F$1` could be named: `theNamedRange`.  Then your formula on `Sheet2!` could refer to it in your formula like this: `=SUM(theNamedRange)`.

Incidentally, it is not clear from your question how you meant to use the range.  If you put what you had in a formula (e.g., `=SUM(Sheet1!A1:F1)`) it will work, you simply need to insert that range argument in a formula.  Excel does not resolve the range reference without a related formula because it does not know what you want to do with it.

Of the two methods, I find the named range convention is easier to work with.

Comment: Works fine for =SUM but not CONCATENATE, I am working with string values e.g.  |The|Quick|Brown|Fox|Jumped|Over|The|Lazy|Dog

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the code provided by Ninja2k because I didn't like that it looped through cells. For future reference here's a version using arrays instead which works noticeably faster over lots of ranges but has the same result:

```
Function concat2(useThis As Range, Optional delim As String) As String
    Dim tempValues
    Dim tempString
    Dim numValues As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    tempValues = useThis
    numValues = UBound(tempValues) * UBound(tempValues, 2)
    ReDim values(1 To numValues)
    For i = UBound(tempValues) To LBound(tempValues) Step -1
        For j = UBound(tempValues, 2) To LBound(tempValues, 2) Step -1
            values(numValues) = tempValues(i, j)
            numValues = numValues - 1
        Next j
    Next i
    concat2 = Join(values, delim)
End Function
```

I can't help but think there's definitely a better way...

Here are steps to do it manually without VBA which only works with 1d arrays and makes static values instead of retaining the references:

1. Update cell formula to something like `=Sheet2!A1:A15`
2. Hit <kbd>F9</kbd>
3. Remove the curly braces `{ and }`
4. Place `CONCATENATE(` at the front of the formula after the `=` sign and `)` at the end of the formula.
5. Hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: For some reason this does not work, it should work. If I concatenate the result of a range of cells it only returns the first cell. Odd.