# Reference range of text cells from another sheet

Tags: excel

I have cells O4: P23 blank in 'Sheet1'.  I want the contents of these cells to be populated with the contents from cells B2: C21 (same size range) from 'Sheet2'.  If I copy and paste the contents from Sheet2 in to the location I want in Sheet1, it works just like I want, but if I try to use referenced formulas in O4 of Sheet1, I get the #Value! error.  I have tried this already:

```
='Sheet2'!B2:C21
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993845/how-do-i-reference-a-cell-range-from-one-worksheet-to-another-using-excel-formul) has a similar problem, but the solutions listed seem like they are overcomplicated and I feel like it should be much easier than this.  I am using Excel 2013 and the worksheet is macro enabled, but I'm hoping to stay away from macros if possible.

Comment: I want to use the references instead of copy pasting because of an IF statement:  

    IF ('Sheet1'!A1=1, 'Sheet2'!B2: C21, IF('Sheet1'!A1=2, 'Sheet2'!D2: E21, ...))

I've identified the root of the problem in the IF statement to be referencing a range of cells from another sheet, hence the title of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In O4 enter the formula

```
=Sheet2!B2
```

No $ signs in the cell reference. This is a relative cell reference, i.e. it will change when copied across (to `=Sheet2!C2`) and down (to `=Sheet2!B3`).  Copy across to P4 and down to row 23.

Note that a cell reference for a range does NOT have a space after the colon, like you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Thank you, the reason I did not recognize this solution in the first place was some of the cells being referenced were merged and led to a similar range reference problem.

Comment: Another reason to avoid merged cells.